# Enviar lista de emails com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#j_envia-lista').click(function(){ 
      var dados = $('#j_exibe-envio');

      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "usuario/enviar-newsletter.asp",
          success: function(resposta) {
              dados.html(resposta);
          },
          beforeSend: function(){
            dados.html('Enviando emails...');
          },
          error: function(data) {
              dados.html('Erro ao enviar!');
          }
    });
  return false;
  });
```

Tenho essa função em JQUERY que executa uma página asp com um while trazendo emails de usuários. (Um select com um while simples, nem preciso postar aqui).

A questão é que essa função só traz no retorno quando todo WHILE é executado. Ou seja, o usuário fica esperando toda a execução para só no fim visualizar a lista dos emails enviados.

Eu gostaria de exibir os emails um a um, a medida que o looping(while na página ASP) seja executado e os email do usuário enviado JÁ IR PRINTANDO NA TELA (RETORNO).

É complicado fazer isso?

Comment: Vc precisará também criar uma coluna no BD para marcar que o email já foi enviado. Vou postar uma resposta que lhe servirá e modelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente o ASP só vai *liberar* o retorno para o AJAX quando o `while` for completado. Para isso você deveria fazer um select no banco de apenas 1 email por vez:

```
select email from tabela where enviado = '0'
```

Note que na cláusula `where` da query usei uma coluna `enviado` com o valor igual a `0`. Você terá que criar uma coluna `enviado` (ou o nome que quiser) para poder marcar que aquele registro que contém o email já foi enviado. Crie uma coluna *int* de tamanho `1` com valor padrão `0`. Assim, quando o email for enviado, irá alterar o valor de `0` para `1`. Aí quando aquele email referente àquele registro for enviado, ele não será buscado pelo select, apenas os que possuem o valor `0`, até que todos tenham valor `1` e finalizar o envio.

Na parte do AJAX você deverá usar o evento de forma recursiva, assim:

```
$('#j_envia-lista').click(function(){ 
   var dados = $('#j_exibe-envio');
   var $this = $(this);
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "usuario/enviar-newsletter.asp",
      success: function(resposta) {
         if(resposta.trim()){
            dados.append(resposta);
            $this.click();
         }else{
            dados.append('<div>Envio finalizado!</div>');
         }
      },
      beforeSend: function(){
         if(!$("#enviando_").length) dados.html('<div id="enviando_">Enviando emails...</div>');
      },
      error: function(data) {
         dados.append('<div>Erro ao enviar!</div>');
         $this.click();
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Note que adicionei div's nas mensagens para que cada uma ocupe uma linha diferente no contêiner `#j_exibe-envio`. E o `$this.click();` irá chamar novamente o evento.

Na parte do ASP você deverá fazer algo assim:

```
<%
set rs = conn.execute("select id, email from tabela where enviado = '0'")
if not rs.eof then
   'achou algum registro
   conn.execute("update tabela set enviado = '1' where id = '"& rs("id") &"'")
%>
<div><%=rs("email")%></div>
<%
else
   ' zera todos os registros novamente para um novo envio
   conn.execute("update tabela set enviado = '0'")
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing
%>
```

Note que o ASP irá enviar como resposta o email dentro de uma div (`<div><%=rs("email")%></div>`) quando achar algum registro. Se não achar nada, o AJAX terá como resposta um vazio e finalizar o envio sem disparar novamente o evento.

Comment: Deus lhe pague cara. Rs. Então...eu uso nesse campo de controle a data atual que fica marcada o ultimo envio. Nesse campo criei um index. Nesse While eu limito o envio para quanto eu quiser, porque são muitos email, então envio em lotes, não envio todos. Assim que é enviado cada email esse campo de status (data_atual) é atualizado com a data atual. Ai fica o controle quando foi a ultima vez que enviei pra quando quiser enviar novemante e não repetir o cara.

Comment: Amahã vou implementar seu código. Com certeza irei usar.

Comment: O evento recursivo que é a chave do que quero.

Comment: Eu não testei, talvez precise de algum ajuste, mas o caminho é esse. Boa sorte!

Comment: Olhando assim sem testar com muitos emails ele entra em um lopping né. Vou colocar algum limite no asp. Uma boa não ter o While. Bate e volta.

Comment: Vo usar um delay que tenho aqui a cada lote enviado também. Muto bom cara. Brigadão.

Comment: É, tipo um looping enquanto houver registros com a coluna enviado = 0

Comment: Fiz aqui, deu certinho. Só uma coisa me intrigou, mesmo não colocando delay ele demora uns 20 segundos entre um envio e outro. Será a demora do select? Já que o banco tem mais de 1 milhão de linhas.

Comment: Sim, a demora é no servidor mesmo.